# episerver block not working with xforms

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I'm having some problem with getting XForms to work in a block in EPiServer 7. It's webforms and not MVC.

XForms works when I put them on a normal page, but when I use them on blocks I get a null exception. See below.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: virtualPath

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: virtualPath]
System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options) +11610798
EPiServer.Web.TemplateControlLoader.LoadControl(HttpContextBase httpContext, Type renderType, Object renderData, TemplateControl templateControl, String tag, Action`2 bindDataAction) +214
EPiServer.Web.TemplateControlLoader.LoadControl(HttpContextBase httpContext, IContentData contentData, TemplateControl templateControl, String tag) +223
EPiServer.Cms.Shell.MoveToPlatform.PersonalizationContentControlResolver.ResolveContentControls(ContentArea contentArea, Control parentControl, String tag, String itemCssClass, String itemTagName, Boolean enableEditFeatures) +870
EPiServer.Web.PropertyControls.PropertyContentAreaControl.GetContentRenderers(Boolean enableEditFeatures) +598
EPiServer.Web.PropertyControls.PropertyContentAreaControl.CreateContentAreaControls(Boolean enableEditFeatures) +130
EPiServer.Web.PropertyControls.PropertyDataControl.CreateChildControls() +103
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +182
EPiServer.Web.WebControls.Property.CreateChildControls() +600
System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +182
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +60
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4201
```

I tried to compare with the Alloy templates, but find no difference that should break it like this.

I also tried to debug, but it doesn't stop at any break points that could give any information.

Anyone know what the problem could be? Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem, but not why the problem occured. My guess would be that episerver cached the renderer and try to access an older version of it that did not exist.

Solution was that the renderer for the block seemed to be corrupt in some way. What I did was to delete the webcontrol that was the renderer, enter edit mode and get the error "no renderer was found for block  and then create it again.

So the problem the problem seems not to have been with the xforms module.